# Output for a nested function in r

Tags: r

The code below is one way to model "Snakes and ladders" game:

```
    ladder.df <- data.frame(start=c(1,4,9,21,28,36,51,71,80), end=c(38,14,31,42,84,44,67,91,100))
snake.df <- data.frame(start=c(98,95,93,87,64,62,56,49,47,16), end=c(78,75,73,24,60,19,53,11,26,6))

game<-function(nop){
positions<-c()
curpos <- 0 # Current location
nroll <- 0 # Number of rolls
snakes <- 0 # Number of snakes encountered
ladders <- 0 # Number of ladders encountered
players<-c(1:nop)
ladders2<-c()
snakes2<-c()

for(i in 1:nop){
while(curpos < 100) {
  roll <- sample(6,1) 
  curpos <- curpos + roll 
  nroll <- nroll + 1 
  positions<-append(positions,curpos)

  # Need to check if we landed on a ladder or slide and move forward or back
  if (any(ladder.df$s %in% curpos)) {
    curpos <- ladder.df$e[ladder.df$s %in% curpos]
    ladders <- ladders + 1
  }
  if (any(snake.df$s %in% curpos)) {
    curpos <- snake.df$e[slide.df$s %in% curpos]
    snakes <- snakes + 1 
  }
}
data<-data.frame("Player:"=players[i],"Ladders"=ladders,"Snakes"=snakes,"Number of rolls"=nroll)
print(data)
}
}
```

The code runs fine, however, the output I want ( that is, no. of ladders, snakes and number of throws for **each** player) duplicates the results of the last player, since neither snakes, ladders or no. of throws dependent on i. Question is- how do I fix this? I tried various approaches (like assigning all the 'snakes' values to the vector and call a certain value from a vector, corresponding to the value i) but it will not budge. Thanks for all the support in advance!

Comment: The game ends when "any" player reaches 100. Terms: turn is when one player rolls the die, round is when all players have rolled the die (atleast once - if 6 means an extra turn). There should be a variable to store the "max position" that any player has reached. The current loop will ensure each player wins the game since they're the only one playing. The overall logic should be something like `while (max_position != 100)`. For saving positions etc. of each player, you may want to make a separate data.frame for each round or for each player and store them in a list.

Comment: `positions<-append(positions,curpos)` makes your simulation quadratic in the number of rolls, which would make it not suitable for e.g. Monte Carlo estimation of expected length of the game. Since you don't actually *use* `positions` -- you are making your code slow for no good reason.